# How can I get the number of children from an element with protractor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, css-selectors, protractor

I am using Protractor and I want to know the number of children from an element.

The element I have is a table element.

```
let table = element(by.css('#myTable'));
```

Now I want to assert the number of table entries. How can that be done, based on the table element I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get all child `tr` tags from the table and use `count()` method to get the number of rows present.

```
let table = element(by.css('#myTable'));
let rowCount = table.all(by.css("tr")).count()
```